# ASP.NET MVC Error : Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string , in EF Migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, runtime-error, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to use *update-database* command in Package Manager console for specific target-migration. but this error happened .

> Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

I cant understand whats the cause of the Error.becasue the Migration **up()** methd is empty , and just I need to run it because when I want to add new migration to project , it asks for applying some pending explicit migrations.

Any help?

Comment: Please post the codes of the Entity classes you are migrating. Maybe something is wrong with those

Comment: @UmairFarooq  : thanks for your time, but entity classes worked fine before , I removed some latest migration classes by mistake, also I needed to remove a table and add it again with some new specific relationships. 
but now when I want to update database , it gives me above error message.
Also, the migration class Up() is Empty. Is it something possible to be wrong in Entities?

Comment: If you removed the migration classes by mistake then you have to add those again using enable-migrations command. Because you might have missed something by putting the migration classes manually

Comment: @UmairFarooq  Migrations have already been enabled in project . I used -Force , but what it is subject to my error? I can run some of the migrations, and have issue for some others !

Comment: does your previous database exist still ? Because you might wanna try deleting that and then running update-database command again. I know these couple solutions while facing such problem. Just want to help

Comment: Generate a script so you can see what is happening: update-database -Script.